# Why do I have to access a special BIOS menu to boot?

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, bios

As the title says, everytime I boot I need to access the F12 menu (single-time boot menu),and it says 'Unknow Device [the name of my hard drive]'.

When I boot without the F12 menu, nothing opens, excepted a text saying: No boot device.

I double checked the normal BIOS boot sequence, and the hard drive is first on the list.

It looks like the BIOS doesn't recognize the hard drive under Ubuntu 14.04.3 (latest version) LTS, it was Windows 10 before, and it worked just fine.

It's not specially a big deal, it's just REALLY REALLY annoying to always have to spam F12 at boot to open my computer.

Oh yeah and BTW my computer is the Acer Aspire E15 Laptop.

Thank you !

EDIT: It finally worked with Ubuntu 15.10, I saw another post (which I will post the link if I see it in my history) talking about issues with Win8.1 preinstalled laptops and their BIOS problems. Upgrading to Ubuntu 15.10 and putting the EFI file in my main ext4 partition as well as adding the .efi files to the BIOS accepted files for boot fixed it. I also kept my windows .efi boot manager just in case the motherboard had to boot only from windows boot manager folders, in which case I would have installed the Ubuntu .efi files in that partition to "trick" the motherboard (I don't know if it would've worked...). My BIOS also recognized the .efi files I added as fully fonctionnal "drives" (I could select them to boot from them as separate entities in my F12 menu). I just had to add the Shimx64.efi file to my BIOS allowed boot files and put it first on my boot list and it now boots Ubuntu when I press the power button !
Thanks y'all !

N.B.: I'm sorry for my grammar, I am a french canadian (I did my best) :D

REEDIT: I found the link of the post talking about Windows 8.1 preinstalled PCs and their problems : [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi) (It's the first answer)

Comment: Not sure, but my first try would be to reinstall grub. There are many guides for that procedure, one of the most popular ones is this: http://askubuntu.com/a/88432/367990

Comment: My suspicion is that you've done a BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode install on an EFI-based computer. This is causing problems. You may be able to work around it by adjusting the boot order in your firmware; or you might want to disable the CSM in the firmware and re-install Ubuntu (or at least install an EFI-mode boot loader for the installation you've got). The output (`RESULTS.txt` file) of the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) would be helpful in diagnosing this with more certainty. Post it to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and post the URL here.

Comment: Acer requires a supervisory password and then you have to set trust on the Ubuntu/grub efi boot files.  See steps 34 onwards: http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Comment: Exactly @oldfred, that's what I did to authorize the Ubuntu .efi files to get along with my BIOS :D